# Length of member names

Tags: c#

What is the maximum number of characters (roughly) for a member (variable,property,method) name  beyond which the descriptive ability of the name isn't just worth it ? Any rules of thumb ?

Comment: This seems like a very subjective question. Keep it as simple as it can be, but no simpler. Enough to know what it is, but not a story.

Comment: Note that Microsoft has specific guidelines about naming itself at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx .  One in particular that is relevant to this question is to avoid abbreviations and contractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My rule of thumb is: If this variable name was a URL, would people not want to type it in to go to my website? If the answer is yes, then it's too long.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard rule of thumb. 8 Characters is just someone's opinion. I say:

If the member name is hard to read then it's too long. Example:

```
foo.TemperatureWhenInitializedAndAllocated = 56.7;
```

If it's easy to read, then it's better.

```
foo.Temperature = 56.7 // put the extra description in comments... When initialized and allocated
```

But most of all the member variable names must make sense, be concise, easy to read, and not cryptic or mysterious.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio will accept user defined types with a length no more than 512 characters.
Even though it's possible, please don't.

The ECMA standard does not mention a limit.

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm (More specifically Partition II, section 22)

This is the maximum variable name that will compile in Visual Studio 2008:

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var
                oqqdidqhcklcipgkafunpkhibulewkmwzwdtwhqsmgrbjvsdkqtvctskkucuuvduhmoshvnmtlujflogqlmlmawperuqqrblmubosgpxatbzlngtpgnrofsrybeivctnvyuszwdyzpdqvjptdvxtahxqcjxxkjuloywtqjavhjodocipbhstwfmmpobiinfgqwjrrthpzyjnrrliiqwpcalfmpoqqoaxdpflbaygblotedyyavkhrsuutnlvilfmzgldwdyunudxbmulbxhxqgmgjhrxjgtxftaradjeiabxhsavmwpjzsoojziwuxrfvezbnadlndkuxuqbgrgtraautnirpkzjukijltgpcdcoxtqeljhyufwwnyrjuvqldobnsjupbzdehpzezyrbggbvrglyjcsjwoeojwrnjspraitaxkmabfqrekokhgdezmqmkgyhbikbdxwuetqxhapjblbsphxvmfmgumpydupiqjikwyepwsxyijyxhfc
                    = "foo";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From code complete book the author says a good length would be 8 characters. Idea is its easier to type even if you don't have an intellicence IDE.

Comment: Code complete states that names averaging between 8 and 20 chars are ideal

Comment: Why is this an ideal length? Is there a rationale?

Comment: Limiting the names to 8 characters would be a pretty bad idea IMHO, it's not enough to provide a descriptive name...

Answer (score 1):

My rule: one (precise) word is best, two is good, three is acceptable, four is too much.